# Looping through two recordsets in Access and updating entries

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2007

I have two tables in my database which are named Book and ReferencesNum, and they have a one-to-many relationship where Book is the main table. I want to loop through both records and when ever the primary key (Title) from Book is equal to a record that has the same Title in ReferencesNum I want to take the ID Number from the record that is in Book and put the same value in the ID field that is in ReferencesNum.

I want to do this by using SQL Statments. I got it for VBA but I am trying to use SQL statments instead.

VBA Code:

```
Sub GoThroughX()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("Book")
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("ReferencesNum")

  rs1.MoveFirst
  Do Until rs1.EOF
    rs2.MoveFirst
     Do Until rs2.EOF
       If rs1![Title] = rs2![Title] Then
         rs2.Edit
         rs2![ID] = rs1![ID]
         rs2.Update
       End If
      rs2.MoveNext
    Loop
 rs1.MoveNext
 Loop

rs1.Close
rs2.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

With SQL:

```
Sub UpdateX1()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("Book")
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("ReferencesNum")

rs2.MoveFirst

 Do Until rs2.EOF

    SQLstr = "UPDATE ReferencesDoc " & _
             "SET ID = rs1![ID] " & _
             "WHERE [Title] = rs1![Title];"
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQLstr

 rs2.MoveNext
 Loop

 MsgBox "Done"

 End Sub
```

The Code with SQL works but it keeps prompting a box where I have to type in the ID and Title and then it changes the ID values.

How can I make it so that it would stop asking the ID and Title values and just go through the table it self, like the VBA Code.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reevaluate your design on this. Why are you using recordsets in the first place?

You are creating an O(N^2) process where you could accomplish this as O(1) by using a single SQL statement to update all records. If you are intent on using DAO then look into the DAO.QueryDef object as opposed to the DAO.Recordset object to accomplish the SQL solution.

In answer to your question above, though, you are receiving prompts because you are using the wrong syntax when referring to the fields in your recordsets so Access thinks you want to supply a parameter. It's been a long time but I believe the proper syntax is rst.("fieldName") or by using the rst.fields("fieldName") to reference a column in your recordset.

But really, you want to stay away from the recordsets here.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the solution, with setting access warning to off :
Best regards

```
'With SQL:

Sub UpdateX1()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("Tabl1")
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("Tabl2")


'dans un tel cas, ne pas oublier de régler les warnings à false
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
rs1.MoveFirst
Do Until rs1.EOF

rs2.MoveFirst

 Do Until rs2.EOF

    sqlstr = "UPDATE Tabl2 " & _
             "SET fld2 = '" & rs1![fld2] & "'" & _
             "WHERE [fld1] = '" & rs1![fld1] & "';"
    DoCmd.RunSQL sqlstr

 rs2.MoveNext
 Loop
 rs1.MoveNext
Loop
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

rs1.Close
rs2.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

 MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

'With SQL:
'consider to have limited recordscount,
'between your recordset1 and your recordset2
'to update this way, because stills running
'a long time
'And now, you can write more generics !!!
'Have a good luck !

```
Sub UpdateX2()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset

Dim strSQL1 As String
Dim strSQL2 As String


strSQL1 = "SELECT Top 10 fld1, fld2 FROM Tabl1;"


Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL1, dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("Tabl2")


'dans un tel cas, ne pas oublier de régler les warnings à false
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
rs1.MoveFirst
Do Until rs1.EOF

rs2.MoveFirst

 Do Until rs2.EOF

    sqlstr2 = "UPDATE Tabl2 " & _
             "SET fld2 = '" & rs1![fld2] & "'" & _
             "WHERE [fld1] = '" & rs1![fld1] & "';"
    DoCmd.RunSQL sqlstr2

 rs2.MoveNext
 Loop
 rs1.MoveNext
Loop
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

rs1.Close
rs2.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

 MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```